# Compressed y-axis in R studio plotting window

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, raster

I am trying to plot a raster in R Studio and continue to get an image like the one below.  As you can see the y-axis is completely compressed. I am using the this code

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Within R I can create the correct plot.  Moreover, two weeks ago I was running the same code and was able to generate correct raster plots with expanded y-axes.  I suspect the issue is a local problem on my machine but am out of ideas. I have tried to clear all the plots, restart R Studio, restart my computer, and also test different raster layers. I have also tried `dev.off()`. My session info is documented below.  Again, I was running the same code last week and had no issues.

Any suggestions as to why I have the compressed y-axis in R Studio when plotting would be appreciated.

**Addition** To address the comment below, the issue does not persist when plotting non-rasters unless the new plot is called after a raster plot has been called.  For example, if I open a new session of R Studio and plot `plot(-50:50)` then all looks OK.  If I open R Studio and try to plot a raster, which results in the compressed y-axis, then all subsequent plots will also have a compressed y-axis unless I click the Clear All button and then run `dev.new()` Then `plot(-50:50)` will look OK.

If I run `x11(); plot(r)` I get the following error indicating problems with the y-axis.

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
>   In addition: Warning messages
>   1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion    2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

I am nut sure how to open or test the

```
png(r <- tempfile(fileext='.png'))
```

code provided in the comment.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.4-20 sp_1.2-1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.3      lattice_0.20-29 Rcpp_0.11.2     rgdal_0.9-1    
[5] tools_3.1.3
```

Comment: Presumably other graphics devices, e.g. `png` work? Does `png(f <- tempfile(fileext='.png')); plot(r); dev.off(); file.show(f)` produce the expected plot? What about `x11(); plot(r)`? And is the same issue seen for non-raster plots (e.g. `plot(-50:50)`)?

Comment: @jbaums Thanks for the comment.  see additions above.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Re the `png` comment above, it should run fine exactly as I posted it, but my guess is that it'll behave the same way as the `x11` device. All I can really suggest is to update R and RStudio and see if that helps.

Comment: @jbaums Thanks!  Both of your coding suggestions produce the correct plot.  This issue seems to be with the default R Studio plotting window.  If I keep the `x11()` window open then I can correctly plot rasters.  If I close the `x11()` window and then plot in the R Studio window, I again get the compressed y axis.  I have installed the newest R Studio and get the same result.  I have not installed a newer R, as the issue is only in R Studio.  All is working fine in R.